# How to add a link to this Test case using COM

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I could create a "Test Case" work item using the following code:

```
Dim workItemType As WorkItemType
workItemType = teamProject.WorkItemTypes("Test Case")

Dim testcase As New_ Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem(workItemType)
testcase.Fields("Title").Value = "Test Case title1"
```

Please advise me how to add a link to this Test case using COM. Here in this case i want to add a user story as a link to this test case

Comment: I don't see what COM has to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two API's available. One is in .NET and the other is Java. If you are using VSO or TFS 2015 you also get REST API's.

If you want to create work items with COM then you would likely have to create a web service in .NET that creates your work item, and then call that from COM.

Linking work items in .net can be achieved by: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2010/02/27/tfs-api-part-22-create-link-between-work-item-parent-child-etc/

Comment: i created test case in TFS using the below code. -------------------------Dim workItemType As WorkItemType
workItemType = teamProject.WorkItemTypes("Test Case")

Dim testcase As New_ Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem(workItemType)
testcase.Fields("Title").Value = "Test Case title1"-----------------------------Now i want to add a link to this test case. MSDN provides classes like Link and WorkItemLink but i dont know how to impmlement this. plzz help